# Is this efficient? Elegant?

Tags: refactoring

I'm rather new to programming and I'm quite sure this code will look ugly to most on this site. That is why I'm here.

I'm betting that many of you have awesome tips for a newbie on how to clean up this code and/or make it more efficient. Keep in mind I am a seriously new programmer and if it is too advanced it's likely to go over my head.

```
import random
cscore = 0
pscore = 0
print 'I would like to play a game. \nThe name of the game is Rock, Paper, Scissors.'
rest = 'y'
while (rest == 'y'):
    pick = ['r', 'p', 's']
    b = (random.choice(pick))
    a = raw_input ('\nFirst Letter ')
    if a == 'r' or a == 'R':
        a = 'Rock'
    elif a == 'p' or a == 'P':
        a = 'Paper'
    elif a == 's' or a == 'S':
        a = 'Scissors'

### assign name to computer's answer
    if b == 'r':
        b = 'Rock'
    elif b == 'p':
        b = 'Paper'
    elif b == 's':
        b = 'Scissors'    
    print 'You picked ' + a + '\nAnd I picked ' + b



##### compare picks
    if a == 'Rock' and b  == 'Rock':
        print 'Silly, we both picked Rock, \nthat means we tied.'
    elif a == 'Rock' and b == 'Paper':
        print 'Yes! Paper smothers Rock, therefore, I win.'
        cscore = cscore + 1
    elif a == 'Rock' and b == 'Scissors':
        print 'Crap, Rock smashes Scissors. You win.'
        pscore = pscore + 1
    elif a == 'Paper' and b  == 'Paper':
        print 'Silly, we both picked Paper, \nthat means we tied.'
    elif a == 'Paper' and b == 'Scissors':
        print 'Yes! Scissors cut Paper, therefore, I win.'
        cscore = cscore + 1
    elif a == 'Paper' and b == 'Rock':
        print 'Crap, Paper smothers Rock. You win.'
        pscore = pscore + 1
    elif a == 'Scissors' and b  == 'Scissors':
        print 'Silly, we both picked Scissors, \nthat means we tied.'
    elif a == 'Scissors' and b == 'Rock':
        print 'Yes! Rock smashes Scissors, therefore, I win.'
        cscore = cscore + 1
    elif a == 'Scissors' and b == 'Paper':
        print 'Crap, Scissors cut Paper. You win.'
        pscore = pscore + 1
    print '\nThe score is now Computer ' + str(cscore) + ' Human ' +     str(pscore)
    rest = raw_input ('\nWould you like to play again? y or n ')
print '\nThank you for playing. The final score was Computer ' + str(cscore) + ' Human ' + str(pscore)
if cscore > pscore:
    print 'Ha!, I won and you lost.'
elif cscore == pscore:
    print 'We tied in the overall score, you are a worthy opponent.'
elif cscore < pscore:
    print 'You beat me, you low down mangy son of a gun. You must have cheated.'
```

Comment: This site is for code that has problems.  For code review, check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of that.